# Ошибка - TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, список

Может кто подсказать как исправить?

> Cursor.execute(_SQL, (pricelist['name']))
>   TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

```
def BB_parse(base_url, headers):
    pricelist = []
    session = requests.Session()
    request = session.get(base_url, headers = headers)
    if request.status_code == 200:
        soup = bs(request.content, 'lxml')
        container_main = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'content-wrapper'})
        for c1 in container_main:
            try:
                article = c1.find('div', {'class': 'article'}).text.strip().replace("Артикул: ", "")
                name = c1.select('h1')[0].text
                description = c1.find('div', {'class': 'description'}).text.strip()
                available = c1.find('div', {'class': 'avl'}).text.strip()
                price = c1.find('span', {'class': 'catalog-detail-item-price' }).text.replace("Цена:", "").replace("тг.", "").replace("за шт", "").strip()
                oldprice = c1.find('span', {'class': 'catalog-detail-item-price-old' }).text.replace("Цена:", "").replace("тг.", "").replace("за шт", "").replace(" ", "").strip()
                Category1 = c1.find_all('span', {'itemprop': 'title'})[1].text
                Category2 = c1.find_all('span', {'itemprop': 'title'})[2].text
                Category3 = c1.find_all('span', {'itemprop': 'title'})[3].text
                catalog_detail_pictures = c1.find_all('div', {'class': 'catalog-detail-pictures'})
                image1 = c1.find_all('a', {'rel': 'lightbox'})[0]['href']
                image2 = c1.find_all('a', {'rel': 'lightbox'})[1]['href']
                image3 = c1.find_all('a', {'rel': 'lightbox'})[2]['href']
            except:
                pass


            for count, tag in enumerate(soup.find_all(class_='name')):
                try:
                    if tag.text == 'ISBN':
                       code = soup.find_all(class_='val')[count].text
                    if tag.text == 'Издательство':
                       Publish = soup.find_all(class_='val')[count].text
                    if tag.text == 'Авторы':
                       Authors = soup.find_all(class_='val')[count].text
                    if tag.text == 'Серия':
                       Series = soup.find_all(class_='val')[count].text
                    if tag.text == 'Переплет':
                       Blinding = soup.find_all(class_='val')[count].text
                    if tag.text == 'Количество страниц':
                       Count_Page = soup.find_all(class_='val')[count].text
                    if tag.text == 'Ширина':
                       Width = soup.find_all(class_='val')[count].text
                    if tag.text == 'Высота':
                       Height = soup.find_all(class_='val')[count].text
                    if tag.text == 'Дата последнего тиража':
                       Date = soup.find_all(class_='val')[count].text


                except:
                  pass

            pricelist.append({
                     'name': name,
                     'article': article,
                     'price': price,
                     'oldprice': oldprice,
                     'available': available,
                     'code': code,
                     'Publish': Publish,
                     'Authors': Authors,
                     'Series': Series,
                     'Blinding': Blinding,
                     'Count_Page': Count_Page,
                     'Width': Width,
                     'Height': Height,
                     'Date': Date,
                     'Category1': Category1,
                     'Category2': Category2,
                     'Category3': Category3,
                     'image1': image1,
                     'image2': image2,
                     'image3': image3
                })

        write_sql(pricelist)
        print(len(pricelist))



    else:
        print('ERROR or Done. Status_code = ' + str(request.status_code))

    return pricelist

def write_sql(pricelist):
    DB = {'host': '',
         'user': '',
         'password': '',
         'database': ''}


    conn = mysql.connector.connect(**DB)
    Cursor = conn.cursor()

    _SQL = "INSERT INTO products (Наименование, Артикул, Цена, Старая_цена, Наличие, Код, Издательство, Авторы, Серия, Переплет, Количество_страниц, Ширина, Высота, Дата_тиража, Родительская_категория, Категория, Подкатегория, Картикнка_1 Картикнка_2, Картикнка_3) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
    Cursor.execute(_SQL, (pricelist['name'],
        pricelist['article'],
        pricelist['price'],
        pricelist['oldprice'],
        pricelist['available'],
        pricelist['code'],
        pricelist['Publish'],
        pricelist['Authors'],
        pricelist['Series'],
        pricelist['Blinding'],
        pricelist['Count_Page'],
        pricelist['Width'],
        pricelist['Height'],
        pricelist['Date'],
        pricelist['Category1'],
        pricelist['Category2'],
        pricelist['Category3'],
        pricelist['image1'],
        pricelist['image2'],
        pricelist['image3'],
        ))
    DB.commit()
    Cursor.close()
    DB.close()


BB_parse(base_url, headers)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Переменная `pricelist` является списком. Оператор индексирования [`[]`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) для объекта типа `list` принимает только целые числа (индексы элементов списка) или объект типа [`slice`](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-slice) в качестве аргумента. `'name'` - не является ни целым числом ни `slice`'ом.

Поэтому команда:

```
pricelist['name']
```

вызывает ошибку:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

---

Если я правильно понимаю ваш код, переменная `pricelist` - список записей-словарей, которые вы хотите вставить в SQL таблицу.

Сделать это можно так:

```
records = [tuple(x.values()) for x in pricelist]
Cursor.executemany(_SQL, records)
```

Comment: Спасибо! изменил _SQL заработал. По records не хочет пускать выдает ошибку "mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Failed processing format-parameters; 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable"

Comment: @w2God, а первый вариант работает?

Comment: Работает по вашему примеру, вписав переменные в VALUES. первый вариант не сработал -mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Failed processing format-parameters; 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable, в чем может быть проблема? Может кому то будет полезно.

Comment: @w2God, исправил ответ - попробуйте сейчас пожалуйста...

Comment: @w2God, похоже `mysql.connector` не поддердживает [pyformat (Python extended format codes)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle)

Comment: Проверил, заработало! Благодарю.